# Datagridview - custom sort on column

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview

I have a DGV with a column named 'Position'.  The 'Position' column contains positive and negative values.

Eg:
-2
-1
 1
 2
 3
...
200

Basically, I'd like a nice way to have the negative numbers appear after the positive numbers, with the negative numbers "increasing", so like this:

1
 2
 3
...
199
200
-1
-2
-3

I'm sure I can hack together some ugly for loop, but there must be a better way.

Appreciate any help,
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use linq query

```
items.OrderBy(x => x.Position >= 0).ThenBy(x => x.Position < 0);
```

Comment: What exactly is `items`?  This is a datagridview, not a list.

Comment: Items is your source of items which you are filling up in data grid view.